# Sidekiq PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model, sidekiq

I made a migration changing `branch` to `branch_name` for my `phone_contact` model. I then changed my code to this:

```
class ContactWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker


  def perform(record, service_type = 'test', list_type = 'test')
    phone_contact = PhoneContact.create(
        client_id: record['ClientID'],
        client_name: record['ClientName'],
        branch_id: record['branchID'],
        branch_name: record['branch'],
        unit_id: record['UnitID'],
        member_id: record['MemberID'],
        first_name: record['FirstName'],
        last_name: record['LastName'],
        date_of_birth: record['DateofBirth'],
        most_recent_join_date: record['ChangeDate'],
        old_membership_type: record['OldMembershipType'],
        membership_type: record['NewMembershipType'],
        phone_number: record['HomePhone'],
        email: record['EMailAddress'],
        visits: record['ID__Visits'],
        primary_language: record['PrimaryLanguage'],
        call_type: record['CallType'],
        list_id: "#{Time.new.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")}_#{service_type}_#{list_type}"
    )
  end
end
```

As you can see, `branch` is no longer listed. It clearly states `branch_name:`.

So I pass in a `record`, which is a hash with all of the above attributes to this worker. Regardless of what that hash looks like, this is the error I receive:

> "error_message"=>"PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column \"branch\" of
>   relation \"phone_contacts\" does not exist\nLINE 1: INSERT INTO
>   \"phone_contacts\" (\"branch\", \"branch_id\", \"call_t...\n
>   ^\n: INSERT INTO \"phone_contacts\" (\"branch\", \"branch_id\",
>   \"call_type\", \"client_id\", \"client_name\", \"created_at\",
>   \"date_of_birth\", \"email\", \"first_name\", \"last_name\",
>   \"list_id\", \"member_id\", \"membership_type\",
>   \"most_recent_join_date\", \"old_membership_type\", \"phone_number\",
>   \"primary_language\", \"unit_id\", \"updated_at\", \"visits\") VALUES
>   ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15,
>   $16, $17, $18, $19, $20) RETURNING \"id\"",
>   "error_class"=>"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid"

The error changed to this with no code changes - I was just getting an `unknown attribute: branch_name` error.

What could be causing this? My migration ran fine, when I look in my database i see branch_name, and if I use the Rails Console and manually go through the steps that my code is going through, one by one, it works fine. It only fails when I use `Sidekiq`. I am using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is that the schema is cached. Have you tried restarting all of your workers?

Comment: You were exactly correct. I don't know why deploying to Heroku wasn't forcing a restart, but it wasn't for some reason. I deployed again with no luck, but on the 3rd time deploying everything was reset and they started working. Locally, I just needed to restart Sidekiq and everything worked as it should have.